# AWS Bitnami Magento Caching issues

Tags: magento2.4, varnish, aws

I have been observing difficulties with updating custom magento modules, theme updates, etc which seems related to caching beyond magento caches.

For example when there is a modification version 1 of a particular module, after uploading version 2 files, say I ran magento cli commands for following.

1. setup:upgrade
2. di:compile
3. cache:clean
4. cache:flush
5. Deploy static content

Apart from that I remove inner contents of folder generated, pub/static, var/view_preprocessed folder.

Having all above done (so output should be from version 2), still version ones contents are shown, even when related files are either changed or even removed. Version 2 contents appear automatically after many hours, which seems cleaned 'some how' once a day automatically.

With above , what I practice is naming each version of modules differently, remove previous version with old name, and install new version with new name.

For example, if previous version of module was Vendor_Module1, I disable Vender_Module1 with forced removal of static content, then install next version as a fresh installation with name Vendor_Module2. It works but in fact more time consuming. Also have following issues with my approach.

Say there was an error with Vendor_Module1 (I completely removed it) and installed the fixed version as Vendor_Module2. Having all above steps followed, even when files of Vendor_Module2 not exist, old errors re-appears in most cases. It need to disable non-existing module with static content removal to avoid seeing last old error after a module upgrade with above mentioned approach. This re-appearence of errors related to removed old versions stops after several hours as said above.

Apart from cache clean/flush commands, cleaning of cache through backend is also not helpful on above issue.

Varnish cache is enabled.

Have any of you gone through similar issues and/or if you have any suggestions to overcome these, your feedback is highly appreciated.

Thanks and Best Regards

Indunil

Comment: Did you find a solution? tnks,
Marco

Comment: Not yet apart from rebooting server. One  recently told me restarting php-fpm might help. Couldnt really try that yet

Answer (score 3):

I see that this post is a little old, I'm sorry that nobody has found an answer for it. I have the same issue with the same setup. This is a very good explanation of the problem. My problem also bled into my custom theme updates. I think it has something to do with the way bitnami has the cache set up. After poking around and finding out what caching programs are running I can add these 2 commands to the list of things that don't work:

Clear Memcached:

```
nc localhost 11211
:flush_all
:ctrl+Z
```

and Restarting Varnish

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart varnish
```

The only thing that seems to work for me is rebooting the aws server entirely.

Comment: Thank you very much for your update. Definitely this issue needs more attention.

Answer (score 0):

Adding my finding as an answer here, so it would helpful for others facing same issue.

The issue seems sorted when php-fpm is restarted in addition to magento cli commands following code changes. It worked for me without the need of rebooting server.

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart php-fpm
```